# obtener nombre de icono y mostrarlo en input con JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Como hacer para que al dar `click` en icono, me pueda enviar el nombre del icono  a un `input`, en este caso necesito enviar al `input` lo que contiene el `class` de mi `tag` `i < i class="fa fa-android"> < /i>`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora?, o al menos el código de la pantalla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría agregar un `listener` a la clase `fa` que poseen todos los iconos de `font-awesome` , además de obtener la clase del elemento con `className`.

```js
//Seleccionamos todos los Iconos
var iconos = document.querySelectorAll('.fa');
//El Input a dondese enviará el valor de la clase
var input = document.getElementById('valorIcon');
//Iteramos sobre los iconos para agregar el Listener
for (var i = 0; i < iconos.length; i++) {
  //agregamos el Listener para el evento click
 iconos[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    // asignamos al input el valor de la clase.
  input.value = this.className;
 });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" >
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<input type="text" id="valorIcon">
```

Comment: también puede hacerlo por medio del index(), cada icono tendría un index() de 1 hasta el .length de todos los iconos. y cada número corresponde a cada icono respectivamente.